# Web Scraping ESPN NFL webpage with Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to perform web scraping using Python on the ESPN website to extract historical NFL football game results scores only into a csv file. I’m unable to find a way to add the dates as displayed in the desired output. Could someone help me a way to get the desired output from the current output. The website I am using to scrape the data and the desired output is below:

**NFL Website:**
https://www.espn.com/nfl/scoreboard/_/week/17/year/2022/seasontype/2

**Current Output:**

```
Week #, Away Team, Away Score, Home Team, Home Score
Week 17, Cowboys, 27, Titans, 13
Week 17, Cardinals, 19, Falcons, 20
Week 17, Bears, 10, Lions, 41
```

**Desired Game Results Output:**

```
Week #, Date, Away Team, Away Score, Home Team, Home Score
Week 17, 12/29/2022, Cowboys, 27, Titans, 13
Week 17, 1/1/2023, Cardinals, 19, Falcons, 20
Week 17, 1/1/2023, Bears, 10, Lions, 41
```

---

**Code:**

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

daterange = 1
url_list = []

while daterange < 19:
    url = "https://www.espn.com/nfl/scoreboard/_/week/"+str(daterange)+"/year/2022/seasontype/2"
    url_list.append(url)
    daterange = daterange + 1 


j = 1
away_team = []
home_team = []
away_team_score = []
home_team_score = []
week = []

for url in url_list:
    response = urlopen(url)
    urlname = requests.get(url)
    bs = bs4.BeautifulSoup(urlname.text,'lxml')
    print(response.url)
    i = 0
    while True:
        try:
            name = bs.findAll('div',{'class':'ScoreCell__TeamName ScoreCell__TeamName--shortDisplayName truncate db'})[i]
        except Exception:
            break

        name = name.get_text()
        try:
            score = bs.findAll('div',{'class':'ScoreCell__Score h4 clr-gray-01 fw-heavy tar ScoreCell_Score--scoreboard pl2'})[i]
        except Exception:
            break


        score = score.get_text()

        if i%2 == 0:
            away_team.append(name)
            away_team_score.append(score)

        else:
            home_team.append(name)
            home_team_score.append(score)
            week.append("week "+str(j))

        i = i + 1
    j = j + 1
    
web_scraping = list (zip(week, home_team, home_team_score, away_team, away_team_score))
web_scraping_df = pd.DataFrame(web_scraping, columns = ['week','home_team','home_team_score','away_team','away_team_score'])
web_scraping_df
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

week = 17
url = f'https://www.espn.com/nfl/scoreboard/_/week/{week}/year/2022/seasontype/2'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

all_data = []
for board in soup.select('.ScoreboardScoreCell'):
    title = board.find_previous(class_='Card__Header__Title').text
    teams = [t.text for t in board.select('.ScoreCell__TeamName')]
    scores = [s.text for s in board.select('.ScoreCell__Score')] or ['-', '-']

    all_data.append((week, title, teams[0], scores[0], teams[1], scores[1]))

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=['Week', 'Date', 'Team 1', 'Score 1', 'Team 2', 'Score 2'])
print(df.to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| Week | Date | Team 1 | Score 1 | Team 2 | Score 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17 | Thursday, December 29, 2022 | Cowboys | 27 | Titans | 13 |
| 17 | Sunday, January 1, 2023 | Cardinals | 19 | Falcons | 20 |
| 17 | Sunday, January 1, 2023 | Bears | 10 | Lions | 41 |
| 17 | Sunday, January 1, 2023 | Broncos | 24 | Chiefs | 27 |
| 17 | Sunday, January 1, 2023 | Dolphins | 21 | Patriots | 23 |
| 17 | Sunday, January 1, 2023 | Colts | 10 | Giants | 38 |
| 17 | Sunday, January 1, 2023 | Saints | 20 | Eagles | 10 |
| 17 | Sunday, January 1, 2023 | Panthers | 24 | Buccaneers | 30 |
| 17 | Sunday, January 1, 2023 | Browns | 24 | Commanders | 10 |
| 17 | Sunday, January 1, 2023 | Jaguars | 31 | Texans | 3 |
| 17 | Sunday, January 1, 2023 | 49ers | 37 | Raiders | 34 |
| 17 | Sunday, January 1, 2023 | Jets | 6 | Seahawks | 23 |
| 17 | Sunday, January 1, 2023 | Vikings | 17 | Packers | 41 |
| 17 | Sunday, January 1, 2023 | Rams | 10 | Chargers | 31 |
| 17 | Sunday, January 1, 2023 | Steelers | 16 | Ravens | 13 |
| 17 | Monday, January 2, 2023 | Bills | - | Bengals | - |